# Elastic Search Multi Geo Points

Tags: elasticsearch

Looking for a bit now to see if this is possible.

I have documents in es that have a two geopoints in their mapping.

1. originGeo
2. destinationgeo

I'm looking to create a query that I can find all documents within x miles of originGeo and y miles of destinationGeo.

I'm currently trying this a couple different ways like this:

## 1

This isn't quite what I want as it uses the same distance per geopoint. But, it also seems to only return documents pertaining to the destinationGeo.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "must_not": [{
                        "term": {
                            "system": "boo"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "1mi",
                            "originGeo": {
                                "lat": 33.9962144,
                                "lon": -118.46887759999998
                            },
                            "destinationGeo": {
                                "lat": 34.0348144,
                                "lon": -117.58480250000002
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## 2

This results in a parse error: filter malformed, no field after start_object

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "must_not": [{
                        "term": {
                            "system": "boo"
                        }
                    }]
                },
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "1mi",
                    "originGeo": {
                        "lat": 33.9962144,
                        "lon": -118.46887759999998
                    },
                    "destinationGeo": {
                        "lat": 34.0348144,
                        "lon": -117.58480250000002
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query for ES 2.x and later should do what you need

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "1mi",
            "originGeo": {
              "lat": 33.9962144,
              "lon": -118.46887759999998
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "1mi",
            "destinationGeo": {
              "lat": 34.0348144,
              "lon": -117.58480250000002
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "system": "boo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you're running on ES 1.x, then you can use this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "1mi",
                "originGeo": {
                  "lat": 33.9962144,
                  "lon": -118.46887759999998
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "1mi",
                "destinationGeo": {
                  "lat": 34.0348144,
                  "lon": -117.58480250000002
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "system": "boo"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Val, thanks a lot for help! I got sidetracked with other things, but, it doesn't appear this helps: `nested: QueryParsingException[[myindex] bool query does not support [filter]]; }]"`

Comment: Ok, that means you're still using ES 1.x, right? In that case you can use the second query in my answer.